# Downloading images causes duplication in values and giving error

Tags: python, scrapy

Spider was running ok and saving data in mongodb but suddenly starts saving duplicate values in database and in json and csv also, i remove the code for downloading images and it works fine but i need images, can anyone help me out ?
thanks in advance.

items.py

import scrapy

```
class BucketItem(scrapy.Item):
# define the fields for your item here like:
store_name = scrapy.Field()
category = scrapy.Field()
sub_category = scrapy.Field()
name = scrapy.Field()
unit = scrapy.Field()
price = scrapy.Field()
link = scrapy.Field()
image_urls = scrapy.Field()
images = scrapy.Field()
pass
```

pipelines.py

import pymongo

class BucketPipeline(object):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.conn = pymongo.MongoClient(
        'localhost', 27017
    )
    db = self.conn['bucket']
    self.collection = db['products_tb']

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.collection.insert(dict(item))
    return item
```

spider.py

```
        image_url = [product.css('.productVisuals img::attr(src)').extract_first()]

        items = response.meta['items']
        items['name'] = product_name
        items['unit'] = unit
        items['price'] = product_price
        items['link'] = product_link
        items['image_urls'] = image_url
        # print(items['name'])
        yield items
```

[scrapy.pipelines.files] WARNING: File (code: 400): Error downloading file from https://qne.com.pk/../product_images/14768.jpg> referred in

Comment: `yield items` items looks wrong (you usually yield one item at a time). Please, provide a minimal, reproducible example. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

not sure about the source you're downloading from, but you might find a "data-src" attribute in addition to the "src" attribute...
You might wanna try having an if statement to capture "data-src" if "src" has a standard common..

```
    if product.xpath('.//div..../img[contains(@src, "some_common_text")]'):
     item['image_urls'] = product.xpath('.//div...../img/@data-src').extract()
else:
     item['image_urls'] = product.xpath('.//div...../img/@src').extract()
```

Comment: ok, can you tell me why downloading images causing duplication in records?

Comment: if you check the img filenames (as retrieved from scraping), you'll find duplicated, so most probably those files are over writing themselves.. you can try altering the saved file names:

Comment: go through this
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html#supported-storage